# 20.04.2. Running basic commands like copy and executing shell scripts using runcmd of cloud-init file

Tags: networking, 20.04, bash, scripts, cloud-init

```
#cloud-config

autoinstall:
  apt:
    geoip: true
    preserve_sources_list: false
    primary:
    - arches: [amd64, i386]
      uri: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
    - arches: [default]
      uri: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports
  identity: {hostname: ubuntu-autoinstall, password: "$6$exDY1mhS4KUYCE/2$zmn9ToZsTKLGmw.b4/b.Z2TIZM20JC4QrOQ2aOXJ8yk96xpcCof0kxKwuX1kqLG/y1bJ1f8wxED22bTL4F46P0", username: ubuntu, realname: ubuntu}
  keyboard: {layout: us, toggle: 'null', variant: ''}
  locale: en_US

  # Network interface configuration. Interface name device-specific. Requires modification.
  # Network is nested twice per new autoinstall layout.
  network:
    network:
      version: 2
      renderer: networkd
      ethernets:
        enp3s0: {dhcp4: true}

  # SSH configuration along with keys go here. 
  ssh:
    allow-pw: true
    authorized-keys: []
    install-server: true

  storage:
    config:
    - {ptable: gpt, path: /dev/sda,
      wipe: superblock, preserve: false, name: '', grub_device: false, type: disk,
      id: disk-sda}
    - {device: disk-sda, size: 536870912, wipe: superblock, flag: boot, number: 1,
      preserve: false, grub_device: true, type: partition, id: partition-0}
    - {fstype: fat32, volume: partition-0, preserve: false, type: format, id: format-0}
    - {device: disk-sda, size: 1073741824, wipe: superblock, flag: '', number: 2,
      preserve: false, type: partition, id: partition-1}
    - {fstype: ext4, volume: partition-1, preserve: false, type: format, id: format-1}
    - {device: disk-sda, size: 62410194944, wipe: superblock, flag: '', number: 3,
      preserve: false, type: partition, id: partition-2}
    - name: ubuntu-vg
      devices: [partition-2]
      preserve: false
      type: lvm_volgroup
      id: lvm_volgroup-0
    - {name: ubuntu-lv, volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0, size: 31195136000B, preserve: false,
      type: lvm_partition, id: lvm_partition-0}
    - {fstype: ext4, volume: lvm_partition-0, preserve: false, type: format, id: format-2}
    - {device: format-2, path: /, type: mount, id: mount-2}
    - {device: format-1, path: /boot, type: mount, id: mount-1}
    - {device: format-0, path: /boot/efi, type: mount, id: mount-0}
  version: 1

  cloud_config_modules:
    - runcmd

  cloud_final_modules:
    - scripts-user

  runcmd:
    - [mkdir, nettools]
    - [cp, -r,  /media/cdrom/files/, nettools/]
    - [sh, /nettools/files/setup.sh]
```

I am not able to run the script file (`setup.sh`) after a successful auto-installation using the commands under `runcmd:`. The `setup.sh` file is on a pen-drive, that needs to copied onto the system for running it.  Kindly help me in knowing where I went wrong and how to resolve the mistake.
My assumption is probably a mistake in the syntax of the commands I listed under `runcmd:`. I would also be interested in hearing other ways to make the shell script run after installation, if possible.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You probably need a '/' in front of your references to 'nettools'. In these two commands...
    - [mkdir, nettools]
    - [cp, -r,  /media/cdrom/files/, nettools/]
Otherwise, your runcmd is valid. Are you sure /media/cdrom/files/ is mounted at the point runcmd runs?

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. Tried your suggestion (adding "/" reference), but the runcmd is still not letting me create the folder - "nettools"  after installation. Also, can you kindly elaborate your doubt on /media/cdrom/files ?

Comment: Just meaning that if you do something like "ls /media/cdrom/files" as one of your runcmd items, is it populated with the script you're trying to run later?

Comment: First Problem: I am not able to make a folder - "nettools", even when I tried your suggestion. Second Problem: "/media/cdrom/files" is empty. I left out but checked only after you pointed it out.

Comment: Why do you think your pen-drive is mounted at `/media/cdrom`?  If you want to run scripts _after_ autoinstall is complete then you should use the `late-commands` configuration for autoinstall.